# Update chart using ajax in primefaces

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I have problem with update primefaces component lineChart using ajax.
I create line and commandLink:

```
<p:lineChart id="LineChart" styleClass="lineChart" style="#{analyze.chartBean.lineChartRendered()}" title="#{analyze.chartBean.title}" value="#{analyze.chartBean.lineChartModel}" egendPosition="e" xaxisAngle="60"></p:lineChart>


<p:commandLink id="type-button" actionListener="#{analyze.analyzeListener()}" ajax="true" update="LineChart">Generuj</p:commandLink>
```

in method analyzeListener() I update model of chart. If I change to not-ajax update all renderer is correct?
Where can be problem?

Comment: I have problem with update primafaces component lineChart using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

If You put `ajax=false` **all** page is rendered. This is its normal behavior :)

Comment: Yes, I know that it is normal behavior but I want to obtain this bahowior using ajax.

Comment: Add at the end of analyzeListener method response.sendRedirect("your path target page"). This may work :)